# Using std::conditional with is_class<int>, getting compile error

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, sfinae

I want to have a type which depends on some other class X having X::value_type.
If there is no such typedef inside the other class, I want to just use X by itself.

So I am looking for code like:

```
TypeChecker<X>::value_type  // Here, value_type might be X or X::value_type, depending on X.
```

But my initial attempts are failing, see below:

Here's a program that does not compile:

```
#include<type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct TypeChecker {
    typedef typename std::conditional<
        std::is_class<T>::value,
        typename T::value_type,  // I believe the error is due to this line (could be wrong)
        T>::type value_type;
};

int main()
{
    TypeChecker<int>::value_type x = 3;

    return 0;
}
```

It gives: `error: 'int' is not a class, struct, or union type`

You can try online: [godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/gZK5wr)

I'm confused, because I thought `std::conditional` would choose the right branch, but it seems to be evaluating both of them, in some sense. At least, enough to cause a compile error.

Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `T::value_type` is passed to `std::conditional` as the template argument, when `T` is `int` the expression itself is invalid.

You can do it with class template and partial specialization instead.

```
template<typename T, typename = void>
struct TypeChecker {
    typedef T value_type;
};
template<typename T>
struct TypeChecker<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_class<T>::value>::type> {
    typedef typename T::value_type value_type;
};
```

BTW: `std::is_class` seems to be much loose condition; you can constrain it as *has the member type `value_type`*, e.g.

```
template<typename T, typename = void>
struct TypeChecker {
    typedef T value_type;
};
template<typename T>
struct TypeChecker<T, std::void_t<typename T::value_type>> {
    typedef typename T::value_type value_type;
};
```

Comment: Thanks! Small point for future searchers: `std::void_t` is C++17 (though pretty trivial to implement in my C++14 environment). And a good [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a0FliKwcwXE&feature=youtu.be&t=2153) on the subject.

Comment: Huh, I also thought sure `std::void_t` was in C++14. Maybe because of [CWG 1558](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1558).

Answer (score 2):

`std::conditional` does not "short-circuit". For `std::conditional<C,X,Y>` to even be instantiated as a class type, the three template arguments must all be actual types. There's no way to have a template that can be used with one of its template parameters representing an illegal or unknown type, even if that parameter doesn't directly matter.

Some solutions to your `TypeChecker`:

```
// C++17, using partial specialization SFINAE:
template <typename T, typename Enable = void>
struct TypeChecker {
    using value_type = T;
};
template <typename T>
struct TypeChecker<T, std::void_t<typename T::value_type>> {
    using value_type = typename T::value_type;
};        

// C++11 or later, using function SFINAE:
template <typename T>
struct type_identity { using type = T; };
template <typename T>
type_identity<typename T::value_type> TypeChecker_helper(int); // not defined
template <typename T>
type_identity<T> TypeChecker_helper(...); // not defined
template <typename T>
struct TypeChecker {
    using value_type = typename decltype(TypeChecker_helper<T>(0))::type;
};
```

(Aside: I'm always a bit suspicious of templates that automatically "unwrap" things, like this `TypeChecker`. It could thwart code which specifically wants to use a container or iterator as a value directly.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I agree that auto-unwrap is a bit shady. In my case I have something that works on `vec3`,`vec2`,`vec1` (etc), and I want it to work sensibly on plain `float`, too, just as if that were a `vec1`. Maybe there's a better way...